# Blank Page is coming on SQL fetch

Tags: php, xampp

I am unable to get any output from the database. There are around 13000 entries in my database. However when I am trying to limit the result by 350 then the output is there but when i remove the limit then a blank page is coming. Also when i am fetching other columns then all 13000 queries are being returned.What to do now?

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypassword";
$database = "mydatabase";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$info = array(); 


$sql = "SELECT Customer_Name FROM enquiry ;";


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);


$stmt->execute();


$stmt->bind_result($Customer_Name);


while($stmt->fetch()){

array_push($info, $Customer_Name);
}




echo json_encode($info);
?>
```

Comment: try with appending `WHERE` in you query statement.

Comment: Blank page was the big white spot on the map for developers until they discovered error logs. You are probably running out of memory.

Comment: @marekful but my other columns are returning the result. Only the columns which may have entries with a space like "Ayush Bansal" is creating ruckus

Comment: Not much point to argue. CHECK THE LOGS.

Answer (score 0):

you need to free up the result after process. try this format so that you can get error message too.

```
$execute=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
 if (!$execute) {
     die "Query ($sql) failed: " . mysql_error();
 }
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)) {
    /* loop through a result set even if you don't think you need to. */
    print_r($row);
 }
 mysql_free_result($execute);
```

Also check for max_allowed_packet in SQL.

Comment: but where to check max_allowed_packet? its not in php.ini

Comment: 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824'